# Understanding VBScript "RC18" for decoding the formula

Tags: excel, vbscript

i am making an application for which i have to read the formulas from excel. After many search i was able to read the formula behind a field. But i was not able to understand it. Can somebody help me in this regard?

Formula is

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC18-3*(AVERAGE(C19)/1.128)"
```

Actually i am not uderstanding what is RC18 and C19 at clicking the specific fields it gives this formula.

```
=$R27-3*(AVERAGE($S:$S)/1.128)
```

how `RC18 = $R27`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's Relative Cell Reference. R/C do not mean a cell address.

`RC18` means "The cell in the same row, column 18"

In *relative reference* `R` means "row" and without a number next to it, means the *same* row as the cell wherein the formula resides. (an `R` without a `C` would mean the entire row, e.g., `R1` would be Row 1.)

`C18` means column 18. Similarly, without the `C19` means *Column 19*, or, column S.

Using square brackets for the number indicates an offset, where negative would be a left offset (columns) or an up offset (rows), and otherwise offsets are right (columns) and down (rows), so:

```
R[1]C[1]
```

Would be the cell one row below and one column to the right of the active cell, and likewise:

```
R[2]C[-3]
```

Would be the cell two rows below and three columns left of active cell.

Comment: Works like a charm i understand the formula. Actually decode it ;) :D Thankx mate!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the formula is built by using R1C1 notation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707033/switch-off-r1c1-reference-style-for-recorded-vba-macros) and [here(external)](https://powerspreadsheets.com/r1c1-formular1c1-vba/)

Having RC18 would mean that it refers to the 18th column from the cell you are and, when you check on a given cell in that column, the formula is "translated" to cell in 27th row for that range (the column 18). If any, please show a screen capture to keep on checking.